# Replace "main.swift" as starting point of Swift Command Line Program

Tags: xcode, swift

Is it possible to make Xcode not use main.swift for the Command Line Tool? I could not find anywhere to change this.

Not in info.plist and build settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't override main.swift as default. If you want some other file/class to be your starting point, just call that from the main function.

According to docs

> “main.swift” is implicitly defined as the main entrypoint for the program

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you tell me where exactly you found that statement in the docs?